# Настройка nginx+php7.2-fpm

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, php-fpm, настройка

Купил себе сервер, но настраивать как - толком не знаю.

Согласно гайду  [Веб-сервер на основе Nginx и PHP-FPM](https://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/nginx-phpfpm)
, пытался настроить все как там, со своими дополнениями.

Как оно всегда бывает, половина не сделана, другая - криво.

Проблема в следующем.

При входе на мой домен(прописанный в hosts.ini) начал попадать на файл index.php.
Вроде все логично, кроме того, что больше никуда я попасть не могу.
Создаю новый файл *.php - не открывается(в адресной строке правильный адрес, но по факту все тот же index.php).
Тоже касается вложенных папок.
Через командную строку проверил, все есть.

Подскажите в какую сторону копать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

debian-овские мэйнтэйнеры соответствующих пакетов, как всегда, на высоте (и хорошо, что ubuntu-вцы **в этом месте** ничего не поломали шаловливыми ручками).

---

*чтобы быстро получить результат*, вам надо всего-то (на «чистой» системе, т.е. **до** экспериментов с конфигурацией):

1. поставить 2 (прописью: два) пакета (`nginx-extras` и `php-fpm`).
2. убрать 4 (прописью: четыре) символа комментария в конф. файле nginx-а.
3. (*опционально*) добавить `index.php` в строку, выше которой написано:

   ```
   # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
   ```
4. [пере]запустить сначала fpm, затем nginx.
5. всё.

---

подробнее для новичков:

1. `$ sudo apt install nginx-extras php-fpm`
2. в единственной секции (файла `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default`), где упоминается php, выглядящей примерно так:

   ```
   #location ~ \.php$ {
   #       include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
   #
   #       # With php7.0-cgi alone:
   #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
   #       # With php7.0-fpm:
   #       fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
   #}
   ```

   надо убрать четыре символа комментария (`#`): в начале первой, второй, предпоследней и последней строки.
3. в строку с индексами (в том же самом файле), как и рекомендовано в комментарии, добавить `index.php` (привожу уже отредактированную строку):

   ```
   # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
   index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
   ```
4. `$ sudo service php7.0-fpm restart; sudo service nginx restart` (имя сервиса содержит версию php, в вашей системе могут быть другие цифры. уточните по имени файла в каталоге `/etc/init.d`)
5. это действительно всё. поместите файл index.php в каталог `/var/www/html` и смотрите на результат:

   ```
   $ curl http://localhost
   ```

---

однострочник для docker-а, демонстрирующий истинность изложенного выше:

```
$ docker run --rm -ti ubuntu:16.04 bash -c '{ apt update && apt install -y nginx-extras php-fpm curl && sed -r -i "/(location.*php|sock)/{s/#//;N;s/#//};/nginx-debian/{s/ / index.php /}" /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default && service php7.0-fpm start && service nginx start && echo "<?php echo \"пхп\n\";" > /var/www/html/zzz.php; } &>/dev/null && curl http://localhost/zzz.php'
```

выдаёт строку:

```
пхп
```

что и требуется.

Comment: Хм. Вроде бы понял. Но не до конца.
У меня на текущий момент в любых директориях и вместо любых файлов - index.php.
    Проблема не в том, чтобы добиться отдачи index.php, а чтобы отдавалось хоть что-то иное, из другой директивы, другой файл из той же.
На текущий (нерабочий) момент, у меня такие настройки - https://pastebin.com/mXJzEiRr

Comment: хотите разобраться в том, что именно вы наконфигурировали? похвально. но это вам придётся делать самостоятельно (или нанять специалиста). не хотите? удалите всё что наконфигурировали и выполните четыре предложенных шага. p.s. работать будет не только index.php (исправил в примере для docker-а index.php на zzz.php, для пущей убедительности)